# Microsoft Office Word 2013 - Turn Off the Dang Templates

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013

When you open Word 2013, it automagically offers you up several templates to choose from for use. 'Welcome to Word', 'Blog Post', 'Icon design', etc.

These are interesting and I am proud of the engineers who conceived them, but this is strongly against my desire and intent with Word - to make a document. **Starting From Scratch...**

**Question**
How do you modify the Word opening sequence? Specifically to just open a new blank document on open?

*Example of Templates*
[image: Example illustration of the templates]

It is hard for me to understand why this is a question that needs asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Press "WIN+R" key combination to launch RUN dialog box then type regedit and press Enter. It'll open Registry Editor.
2. Now go to any of following keys according to your requirements:

`For Microsoft Word 2013:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Word\Options`

3. In right-side pane, create a new DWORD DisableBootToOfficeStart and set its value to 1

[image]

4. That's it. It'll immediately disable Start Screen in your desired Office 2013 application.

If you want to re-enable Start Screen in future, simply set DWORD value to 0 or delete the DWORD.

**Alternative method:**

in WORD 2013, go to `FILE` -> `Options` -> uncheck `Show the Start screen when this application starts`

Comment: Bilo - this may be the geekiest, and coolest Stack Exchange answer I've gotten yet :). THANK YOU

Answer (score -1):

Go to Settings, General, and uncheck the box next to 'Show Document Gallery when opening Word'

Comment: There is no "Setting" directly in the Word UI. There is an "Options" button in the File tab/view, and the accepted answer already shows how to find the correct setting in this Options dialog.